# Customize ADFS dropdown list to Tiles

Tags: adfs, tiles

We have our ADFS server 2016 set up and have customized the login page to include our logos. However, we would like to customize the  page after users login such that users see the SSO apps as tiles instead of a drop down. Has anyone tried this before? Any leads to how it can be done is appreciated.

Thanks!